# Ubuntu 14.04 stay to the loading page after an update

Tags: boot, gnome, 14.04

I use Ubuntu 14.04 with gnome 3.

I updated Ubuntu yesterday. Now, I am trying to boot and it stay as the gnome loading screen. I pressed escape and I have this trace :
[image]

`GNOME Display Manager` fail and the process is very slow for `Stopping System V runlevel compatibility` and `Stating CUPS printing spool/server`.

I tried do `CTRL+ALT+F1` to go in the terminal and I tried to remove CUPS. The problem is the same. I also tried to do an update and to check packages via the grub menu without success.

It's hard to work on the problem because I don't know what is the cause of the bug.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my issue. I tried to `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm` and it said than the package is broken or partially installed. So I tried to do `sudo apt-get install gdm` and reconfigure it again and it works.

For googlers : gdm is for Gnome Display Manager.